# Failed to login to Linux shell with passwd generated by mkpasswd -m sha-256

Tags: linux, login, busybox

I am working on an embedded Linux system, where busybox (1.31.1) is used as init.
I enabled login in /etc/inittab but I failed to login to system with invalid password.
The /etc/shadow in rootfs is generated on host with `mkpasswd -m "sha-256" "000000"`, but in busybox in the target, I could not login with password '000000' in console.

I tried in the target with `passwd user` in adb shell (which does NOT need to login) to re-set the password to 000000, then I can use it to login from serial console.

I also tried in the target with `echo "user:000000" | chpasswd -c SHA256` through adb shell, and I can also login to system with the 000000 from serial console.

I checked the busybox configuration, following options are enabled.

```
#
# Login/Password Management Utilities
#
CONFIG_FEATURE_SHADOWPASSWDS=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_PWD_GRP=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_SHADOW=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_CRYPT=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_CRYPT_SHA=y
CONFIG_ADD_SHELL=y
CONFIG_REMOVE_SHELL=y
# CONFIG_ADDGROUP is not set
# CONFIG_FEATURE_ADDUSER_TO_GROUP is not set
# CONFIG_ADDUSER is not set
# CONFIG_FEATURE_CHECK_NAMES is not set
CONFIG_LAST_ID=0
CONFIG_FIRST_SYSTEM_ID=0
CONFIG_LAST_SYSTEM_ID=0
CONFIG_CHPASSWD=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_DEFAULT_PASSWD_ALGO="des"
CONFIG_CRYPTPW=y
CONFIG_MKPASSWD=y
# CONFIG_DELUSER is not set
# CONFIG_DELGROUP is not set
# CONFIG_FEATURE_DEL_USER_FROM_GROUP is not set
CONFIG_GETTY=y
CONFIG_LOGIN=y
# CONFIG_LOGIN_SESSION_AS_CHILD is not set
CONFIG_LOGIN_SCRIPTS=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_NOLOGIN=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SECURETTY=y
CONFIG_PASSWD=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_PASSWD_WEAK_CHECK=y
```

I tried to change the 'des' to 'sha256' for busybox, the same as buildroot. But still failed to login to system from serial console.

So I don't know to fix it.

Comment: Is the `/etc/shadow` file correctly formatted? Does the user exist? Is it the same user you set the password for? Can you try setting the password with `passwd` on the embedded system instead, or doesn't `passwd` exist there? What Linux is the system based on?

Comment: The /etc/shadow is updated with the password generated by `mkpasswd -m "sha-256 " "000000"` accordingly. The user does exist. I can update its password by using `passwd` in adb shell, then I can login from serial console with the password just set. The Linux is 5.10.22. Busybox is built along with other packages within buildroot.

Comment: it's not a good idea to edit /etc/shadow directly.  use `chpasswd` instead.  `chpasswd -e` if the password is already encrypted.  see `man chpasswd` for details.

Comment: I am working on an embedded system, so I tried `passwd user` in target system to set a password to user that can login to system successfully. But in the building host, building script is using `mkpasswd -m "sha-256" "000000"` and `sed` to update the `target_rootfs/etc/shadow`. So I think you just suggested to use `chpasswd -e` in target, right? If so, that is NOT I try to solve. I am trying to solve the building script in host which can generate right `etc/shadow` which can be used to login to target system when the rootfs is deployed to target for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

With tons of testing and googling, I think I found the fix to this issue.

In the busybox configuration, disable selection of 'Use internal shadow password functions', then I can login to busybox with the password from serial console.

Although it is fixed, but I still don't know how does this option impact the login process, if someone has detailed info, that will be great.